# View current user process ancestors and formatting the output

Tags: linux, shell, process, ps

I'm using `ps -eo ppid,pid,cmd` to view all process, and how can I format the output to view like below?

Only given PID and its ancestor will print (until init).

```
23464   current
  |
23211   bash
  |
23210   sshd: xxW
  |
23193   sshd: WWcccv
  |
 728    /usr/sbin/sshd –D
  |
  1     init
```

I'm writing a script to view ancestral process using PID without using `pstree`, if possible.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe something like:

```
#! /bin/bash -
pid=${1?Please give a pid}
sep=
while
  [ "$pid" -gt 0 ] &&
    read -r ppid name < <(ps -o ppid= -o args= -p "$pid")
do
  printf "$sep%$((3+${#pid}/2))d%$((4-${#pid}/2))s%s\n" "$pid" "" "$name"
  sep=$'  |\n'
  pid=$ppid
done
```

Which gives:

```
$ that-script "$$"
13612  /bin/zsh
  |
 4137  SCREEN screen -xRS main
  |
 4136  screen screen -xRS main
  |
 4130  zsh
  |
 4128  xterm
  |
  1    /sbin/init splash
```

That's a bit sluggish as it runs one `ps` per process in the ancestry. You can improve it by running `ps` to retrieve all the information at once and post process it with `awk` for instance:

```
#! /bin/sh -
pid=${1?Please give a pid}
ps -Ao pid= -o ppid= -o args= |
  awk -v p="$pid" '
    {
      pid = $1; ppid[pid] = $2
      sub(/([[:space:]]*[[:digit:]]+){2}[[:space:]]*/, "")
      args[pid] = $0
    }
    END {
      while (p) {
        printf "%s%*d%*s%s\n", sep, 3+length(p)/2, p, 4-length(p)/2, "", args[p]
        p = ppid[p]
        sep = "  |\n"
      }
    }'
```

Answer (score 2):

What about using pstree -spa ?
It will show both predecessors and ancestors for the given pid, including pid and command lines.

```
$ pstree -spa 3056
systemd,1
  └─upowerd,3056
      ├─{gdbus},3071
      └─{gmain},3069
```

Comment: that's the answer I was looking for. `pstree -spa $$` uses the shell's PID as a start

Answer (score -1):

Place pid, ppid's into array. Recursive function or loops to walk through the array, printing only the desired pid and ppid entries.